# MSVC2013 how to declare reference to array at arbitry address?

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

This works:

```
char anArray[256] = {};
char (&refToAnArray)[256] = anArray;
```

This fails:

```
char (&refToAnArrayAtArbitryAddress)[256] = *reinterpret_cast<char(*)[256]>(0xDEADBEEF);
```

With:

```
error C2101: '&' on constant
```

Why does it fail and how do I fix it?

P.S I'm well aware that casting 0xDEADBEEF to a pointer to a 256 element array is dangerous, but its for a 32-bit game hack so I need it.

Comment: Seems to work in other compilers, fails in msvc2015 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a compiler bug, workaround is:

```
char(* const cTheArray)[256] = reinterpret_cast<char(* const)[256]>(0xDEADBEEF);
char(& TheArray)[256] = *cTheArray;
```